# Strongswan + xl2tpd vpn client Assigning static ip address for ppp interfaces

Tags: strongswan, xl2tpd

I have strongswan + xl2tpd vpn client working, it assigns ip address to ppp interface via dhcp from vpn server, how can i assign static ip for the ppp interface discarding dhcp

Comment: Same here. There is no solution although I googled for a whole day.

Comment: in my case vpn server is ra by me, so i wrote a script in server to assign a static ip for the client via dnsmasq ,